# Java, Как сделать точную задержку для секундомера?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Есть следующий метод запуска секундомера. Ещё не дописан до конца, но работает.

```
private void startStopwatch() {

        stopwatchRunning = true;

        Thread thread = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                while (stopwatchRunning) {

                    msCounter++;

                    msStr = String.valueOf(msCounter);
                    secStr = String.valueOf(sec);
                    minStr = String.valueOf(min);

                    if (msCounter < 10) {
                        msStr = "0" + msCounter;
                    }

                    if (msCounter == 99) {
                        //Прошла ещё 1 секунда
                        sec++;
                        msCounter = 0;
                    }


                    //timeViewStopwatch.setText(msStr);
                    timeViewStopwatch.setText(minStr + ":" + secStr + ":" + msStr);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                }

            }

        };

        thread.start();

    }
```

Проблема в том, что когда я проверил секундомер по часам, он отстал на целых 13 секунд...

P.S. Делать задежку через TimeUnit я тоже пробовал, но он как отставал, так и отстаёт.

Comment: Выводите "текущее время" - "время запуска". и задержку в секунду/полсекунды можно ставить. Никто не гарантирует, что у вашего потока все время мира и будет работать только он, отсчитывая миллисекунды.

Comment: Но мне нужно, чтобы он считал в реальном времени

Comment: Нужно спать меньше на то время, что затрачено на выполнение кода в теле цикла. И задержка маловата - сомневаюсь что этот код может уложиться в 10 мсек

Comment: @MrCookie на обычных ОС (не системах реального времени) в принципе нельзя получить задержку с гарантированной точностью.

Comment: @insolor, но нарисовать таймер, который будет правильно выглядеть, вполне возможно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy приблизительно правильно, достаточно точно/правильно для использования человеком. Но не "чтобы он считал в реальном времени".

Comment: @insolor, так как код явно работает с UI Android, то речь идёт именно о изображении правильного таймера. Я так понял термин "реальное время".

Comment: Вам нужна совсем другая архитектура. Начните отсюда: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeAnimator. Надо обновлять экран не 100 раз в секунду, а столько раз сколько обновляется экран устройства. В каждый момент времени вы пересчитываете изображение времени и обновляете его. Получается точный таймер работающий на частоте экрана телефона.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вашего решения в том, что оно не учитывает время выполнения кода, именно на это время показания расходятся с реальным.

```
private void startStopwatch() {

        stopwatchRunning = true;

        Thread thread = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                long interval = 10;
                long nextTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + interval;
                while (stopwatchRunning) {
                    
                    msCounter++;

                    msStr = String.valueOf(msCounter);
                    secStr = String.valueOf(sec);
                    minStr = String.valueOf(min);

                    if (msCounter < 10) {
                        msStr = "0" + msCounter;
                    }

                    if (msCounter == 99) {
                        //Прошла ещё 1 секунда
                        sec++;
                        msCounter = 0;
                    }


                    //timeViewStopwatch.setText(msStr);
                    timeViewStopwatch.setText(minStr + ":" + secStr + ":" + msStr);

                    long sleep = nextTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (sleep > 0) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(sleep);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    nextTime += interval;
                }

            }

        };

        thread.start();

    }
```

Интервала в 10 мсек может не хватить на выполнение кода итерации и тогда время снова будет расходиться с реальным. Нужно либо увеличить интервал, либо оптимизировать код.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему, использовав готовый секундомер из библиотеки [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). Вот код, он показывает часы:минуты:секунды.сотые доли секунды (насчёт правильности показа часов я не уверен, ещё не успел проверить).

```
    private void startStopwatch() {

        StopWatch stopwatch = StopWatch.createStarted();

        msCounter = 0;

        Thread thread = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                while (stopwatchRunning) {

                    msCounter++;

                    if (msCounter == 99) {
                        msCounter = 0;
                        //sec++;
                    }

                    if (msCounter >= 10) {
                        msStr = String.valueOf(msCounter);
                    } else {
                        msStr = "0" + msCounter;
                    }

                    if (min == 0) {
                        sec = stopwatch.getTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    } else {
                        sec = stopwatch.getTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS) - (min * 60);
                    }
                    if (hr == 0) {
                        min = stopwatch.getTime(TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                    } else {
                        min = stopwatch.getTime(TimeUnit.MINUTES) - (hr * 60);
                    }
                    hr = stopwatch.getTime(TimeUnit.HOURS);
                    secStr = String.valueOf(sec);
                    minStr = String.valueOf(min);
                    hrStr = String.valueOf(hr);

                    if (min >= 10) {
                        minStr = String.valueOf(min);
                    } else {
                        minStr = "0" + min;
                    }

                    if (sec == 60) {
                        sec = 0;
                    }

                    if (sec >= 10) {
                        secStr = String.valueOf(sec);
                    } else {
                        secStr = "0" + sec;
                    }

                    if (hr == 60) {
                        hr = 0;
                    }

                    if (hr >= 10) {
                        hrStr = String.valueOf(hr);
                    } else {
                        hrStr = "0" + hr;
                    }

                    timeViewStopwatch.setText(hrStr + ":" + minStr + ":" + secStr + "." + msStr);

                    try {
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                }

            }

        };

        thread.start();


    }
```

Comment: По сути это то же, что вам предложил в самом первом комментарии Yura Ivanov. И вывести время в моменте в формате `HH:mm:ss.SSS` c этим классом можно просто через `toString()`, без велосипедов : `timeViewStopwatch.setText(stopwatch.toString())`

Comment: С этим методом была какая-то фигня, приложение крашилось

Answer (score 0):

UPD: лучший вариант предложен в [комментарии Станиславом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/2734106).

А этот ответ я не знаю как удалить.

---

`Thread.sleep(10)` спит [*примерно*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) 10мс.
Плюс остальной код выполняется какое-то время, а не мгновенно.
Вот в итоге ошибка и накапливается.

Решение: надо проверять, сколько времени прошло, каждый раз, как поток просыпается.
Например, так:

```java
static long ONE_MILLISECOND_NANOS = Duration.ofSeconds(1).toNanos();

long nextTimeNanos = System.nanoTime() + ONE_MILLISECOND_NANOS;
TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(ONE_MILLISECOND_NANOS);
while(stopwatchRunning && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
  long currentTimeNanos = System.nanoTime();
  long timeLeftNanos = nextTimeNanos - currentTimeNanos;
  if (timeLeftNanos > 0) {
    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(timeLeftNanos);
  } else {
    long milliSecondsPassed = (-timeLeftNanos) / ONE_MILLISECOND_NANOS;
    // обновить число прошедших миллисекунд в UI
    nextTimeNanos = nextTimeNanos + (milliSecondsPassed + 1) * ONE_MILLISECOND_NANOS;
    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(nextTimeNanos - currentTimeNanos);
  }
}
```